# How to assign colors specified within dataframe contents to ggplot geoms?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I am trying to plot a graph of some points with some coloured background regions behind them. I would like the fill colour to be dependent on the "quadrant" name and specified within the dataframe itselt (e.g. "Indifferent" would be pink in the example below). I have tried assigning this column to the values argument of scale_fill_manual, but this appears to have no effect e.g:

```
quadrant_names <- c("Indifferent", "Must be present", "Attractive", "Performance", "Dislike")
quadrant_xmin <- c(-1, 2, -1, 2, -2)
quadrant_xmax <- c(2, 4, 2, 4, 0)
quadrant_ymin <- c(0, 0, 2, 2, -2)
quadrant_ymax <- c(2, 2, 4, 4, 0)
quadrant_colors <-c("pink", "yellow", "blue", "green", "purple")

kano_quadrants <- data.frame(quadrant_names, quadrant_xmin, quadrant_xmax, quadrant_ymin, quadrant_ymax, quadrant_colors)

xpoints <- runif(10, -2, 4)
ypoints <- runif(10, -2, 4)
points <- data.frame(xpoints, ypoints)

  ggplot(data=points, aes(x=xpoints, y=ypoints)) +
    geom_rect(data=kano_quadrants, aes(xmin=quadrant_xmin, xmax=quadrant_xmax, x=NULL,
                                       ymin=quadrant_ymin, ymax=quadrant_ymax, y=NULL,
                                       fill=quadrant_names), alpha=0.2) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(data=kano_quadrants, aes(label=quadrant_names, 
              y=(quadrant_ymin+quadrant_ymax)/2, 
              x=(quadrant_xmin+quadrant_xmax)/2))+
    geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=kano_quadrants$quadrant_colors)
```

Results in:

[image: graph]

How can I get it to assign the fill colours to the appropriate levels of quadrant_name as specified within the dataframe rather than randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map `fill` to `quadrant_colors` and use `scale_fill_identity()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=points, aes(x=xpoints, y=ypoints)) +
  geom_rect(data=kano_quadrants, aes(xmin=quadrant_xmin, xmax=quadrant_xmax, x=NULL,
                                     ymin=quadrant_ymin, ymax=quadrant_ymax, y=NULL,
                                     fill=quadrant_colors), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data=kano_quadrants, aes(label=quadrant_names,
                                     y=(quadrant_ymin+quadrant_ymax)/2,
                                     x=(quadrant_xmin+quadrant_xmax)/2))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!